# Converting 4 bytes to unsigned int

Tags: c, byte, bit

If one has a character array such as

```
char bytes[256]  = "10000011011110110010001101000011";
```

I want to unsigned value of this which would be : `2205885251`

I'm trying to do something along these lines

```
unsigned int arr[256];
for(int i = 0, k=0; i<256; i++, k++)
{
arr[k] = bytes[i]|bytes[i+1]<<8|bytes[i+2]<<16|bytes[i+3]<<24;
}
```

I am obtaining the wrong value: `3220856520`, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: calling your array `bytes` is confusing, since they're clearly **bits**... plus your code is shifting those bits by byte-sized distances, which is definitley not how you'd convert them to actual bits...

Comment: I named it bytes because it's 4 bytes that represent 4 integer values. I don't want to convert them to bits I want to convert to one unsigned int.

Comment: Four integers are 128 bits not 256!

Comment: @Matt: One int has 4 or 8 Byte. 4 int don´t have 4 byte. And you have indeed Bits there, not bytes. And, why is your int-array 256 big too?

Comment: @deviantfan 10000011 = 131. That is 8 bits or 1 byte. This is a character array of 4 bytes. I wanted a 32 bit unsigned int value from this character array. I made my arrays 256 because I do not care about allocation at this point.

Comment: @Matt2234 A simply method, if you do not care about allocation, is to use `char bytes[]  = "10000011011110110010001101000011";` and let the compiler determine the array size of `bytes`.

Comment: @deviantfan Note about `int` byte size.  C11 spec requires `int` to have a _minimum_ range of -32767 to 32767.  This requires at least **2** 8-bit bytes.  Such 2 byte sized `int` are common in 2014 in embedded processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char bytes[256]  = "10000011011110110010001101000011";

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int out;
    int i;

    for (out = 0, i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
        if (bytes[31 - i] == '1')
          out |= (1u << i);

    printf("%u\n", out);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output is](http://codepad.org/LqI62Wor):
2205885251

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Do you know what `|=` does? Do you know what `<<` does? It basically means "set the `i`'th bit in `out`". (Indexed from zero to 31.)

Comment: I do understand now; I had never seen 1u before.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char bytes[256]  = "10000011011110110010001101000011";
    unsigned int value = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< 32; i++)
    {
        value = value *2  + (bytes[i]-'0');
    }
    printf("%u\n",value);
}
```

it outputs: 2205885251

Answer (score 0):

```
char bytes[]  = "10000011011110110010001101000011";
unsigned int k;

k = strtoul(bytes, NULL, 2);
printf("%u \n", k);
```

valter